# Checking the amount of enimies in unity c# is not working for me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, text

I am trying to make it so that there is a counter for the amount of enimies in the current level, and I found some code that should check the amount of enimies left. After you kill them, a destroy(gameobject) command is in place. For some reason, whenever I try to use this, the text does not update and stays on "new text".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class text : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI txt;
    private GameObject[] getCount;
    public float count = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   
    public void Start()
    {
      
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");
        count = getCount.Length;
        txt.SetText(count.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `txt` from the inspector.  Double check that it is the same label you are looking at.  Is your script attached to an object?  Add a `Debug.Log` to Start and see if it logs or not.

Comment: Using FindGameObjectsWithTag in an Update might impact your performance. I suggest having a system that takes care of maintaining a list of active enemies.

Comment: Put all kinds of enemy prefabs in a list. Calculate the data of destroying enemies from the list